# How can I improve shift method for memory efficiency

Tags: c#

I wrote a method that takes an array of numbers and shifts the numbers, and return the shifted array.

As follows:

```
private static int[] ShiftArray(int[] arr, int shift)
{
    shift = shift % arr.Length; 
    int[] tmpArr = new int[shift];
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.Length; i++)
    {
        tmpArr[i] = arr[arr.Length - 1 - i];
    }
    for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= shift; i--)
    {
        int index = Math.Abs(i - shift);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[index];
        }
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = tmpArr[tmpArr.Length - 1 - i];
        }
    return arr;
}
```

I want to improve the method so that it will not spend memory. I would be glad to get an idea about how I can improve it and how I can see how much memory is allocated to this method?

**Edit**

Example 1:

```
Input: int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}, shift:2
Output: int[]{5,6,1,2,3,4}
```

Example 2:

```
Input: int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}, shift:15
Output: int[]{4,5,6,1,2,3}
```

Comment: Is this actually *rotating* the values in the array by `shift` elements? And would it be acceptable to do an in-place shift?

Comment: Your memory overhead is only `shift` elements, what are typical values for `shift` and `arr.Length` ?

Comment: Metthew, yes, its method is rotatting values, how to can i place shift (in place shift will be more efficiency..).
Henk, int types (As you can see in the method).

Comment: Your code has a bug! It reverses the first part of the sequence!

Comment: I can see the type, I asked for values.

Comment: Example1 does a rotate (not a shift), Example2 does something completely different that is neither a shift nor a rotate.

Comment: Metthew, you correct, i will fix my code

Comment: @DavidMichaeli In that case, perhaps my answer below is actually correct for you. :)

Comment: This is a standard problem, solved and well-documented. [Here for example](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an in-place right-rotate of an array as follows:

```
private static int[] ShiftArray(int[] arr, int shift)
{
    shift = arr.Length - (shift % arr.Length);
    Array.Reverse(arr, 0, shift);
    Array.Reverse(arr, shift, arr.Length-shift);
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

However this doesn't quite do what your spec asks for. But it *is* doing a right-rotate.

From your spec:

> Edit: Example 1: Input: int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}, shift:2 Output: int[]{5,6,1,2,3,4}
>
> Example 2: Input: int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}, shift:15 Output: int[]{6,5,4,1,2,3}

My code outputs the same for your example 1, but for example 2 it outputs:

> 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4

which is correct for a right-shift (which will always leave the elements in the same order).

But your spec has some of the elements in a different order, which means it's not really a right-shift but something more complex. (Or there's an error in your spec!)

(The book Programming Pearls by Jon Bentley has an algorithm like this for rotating an array.)

Comment: Thanks, how do can i check the efficiency?

Comment: @DavidMichaeli It doesn't use *any* extra memory because it makes no copies of any parts of the array (other than just one element) - but if by "efficiency" you mean "speed" you can time it using a `Stopwatch`.